# Is there a shortcut in Android Studio to jump from current file to parent class?

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I was wondering if there is a shortcut in Android Studio to jump to parent class from current file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a keyboard-shortcut for `Go To > Definition` (my personal favorite).

- select any class-name bei double-clicking it and then hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

For the super class, just select the class-name which follows `extends`.

---

And there's even a direct shortcut: `Go To > Super Class`.

- place the cursor inside the class definition and hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

---

Alternatively, simply click the "overridden method" icon: [image: IDE icon]

This has the advance, that one does not have to search for the overridden method.

---

[Source code navigation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html) describes these and many others.

(that's also the source of the above image).